# NoClassDefFoundError after refactoring name

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, noclassdeffounderror

I am using the Eclipse IDE to create an Android application compliant with Android 2.2 and higher.  I refactored the name of one of my main activities.  My basic structure is that I have a pseudo home page activity in which other "apps" (actually activities) inside this one app have icons that lead to their respective activity.  I had a class that was originally the head activity for one of these branches in the app, call it Activity.java.  Activity.java ended up just pointing to Activity_Home.java and no longer did anything so I decided to get rid of it.  I deleted Activity.java, rebuilt, then refactored Activity_Home.java to Activity.java, rebuilt.  Got a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
05-01 10:13:12.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15635): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 10:13:12.609: E/AndroidRuntime(15635): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Activity.java
```

so then I renamed it back to Activity_Home.java after fiddling for a bit thinking that might help something.  Completely cleaning and rebuilding before every attempt to launch.  Kept getting the error even though I checked the CLASSPATH and that the .class file was being named correctly.  Eventually I read that someone, though they don't know why this worked, fixed a similar problem by deleting and remaking the file.  I did that.

That seems to have worked, but I don't know why and now every file deeper then Activity_Home.java (eg. there is an activity called by it Activity_Camera.java) is having the same issue.

I obviously do not want to have to delete and remake all of the .java files and even if that fixes the issue I would still like to know WHY this is happening not just HOW TO FIX it.

EDIT 1: Forgot to mention that I already checked the Manifest file for inconsistencies.  The issue is now happening on a class that I did not even rename. Could be part of the automated refactor renaming? (pure speculation)

EDIT 2: Issue with SherlockListActivity. Says it can't find the APK after whatever refactoring I did. When I remove SherlockListActivity it fixes my issues.

Comment: if you are using eclipse, try cleaning the project. Project-->Clean. Sometimes this issue is fixed by this.

Comment: Try to look at the `Markers` view (tab), there you can check all errors and warnings. Android os very good at detecting potential issues runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring name will change the `class` name in the java classess, but not in `manifest` file.

Try to change the class name in `AndroidManifest.xml` also, that will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

1. You initially had a file Activity.java which did nothing but pointed to Activity_home.java.
   From pointing , I assume it opens the Activity_home.java . Whenever you create an Activity , its entry is added in the AndroidManifest.xml file. However, when you delete an activity , I think it is not removed from the manifest file. So Change your main file to MainActivity.java and change its corresponding entry in the manifest like this.

Just check the other activities whether their names and packages are correct in manifest and you are good to go .

```
 <activity android:name="com.raman.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
        </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things you have to check. Those are :

1. Check Package name of your app from menifest.xml and build.gradle both file.
2. Check manifest activity name with full path. If activity path is incorrect then correct it.
3. If problem not solved then execute File--> Invalidate Cache / Restart . Hope problem will solved.
4. If problem not solved then delete build folder and rebuild the project. Now your problem will solved.
   Thanks :)